# Spring Cloud Vault error: nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am trying to use HashiCorp Vault using Spring Cloud Vault on Spring Boot project. I configured my **bootstrap.yml** file to use app role and secret id to get passwords

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: pres
  cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: APPROLE
      app-role:
        role-id: ${role-id}
        secret-id: ${secret-id}
        role: pres-read
        app-role-path: approle
      uri: https://hostname:8200
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: secret
        application-name: pres
  profiles:
    include: dev
```

During startup I get the following exception

```
org.springframework.vault.authentication.VaultLoginException: Cannot login using org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://hostname:8200/v1/auth/approle/login": extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
```

I am using spring-cloud-starter-vault-config dependency to access the vault

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
            <version> 2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Which Vault version are you on? Found this similar sounding issue on github https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/8750 - but not much activity going on in the issue

Comment: @kgorskowski updated the post

Comment: Hi, I did some basic read up, the problem seems to be the tls negotiation between java and golang (vault) - there is more information on that https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35722 sorry but I am out of my waters in this topic. Better check the versions of your components for issues/bug reports regarding this matter

Comment: @kgorskowski Thanks for the link. I followed workaround from here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35722#issuecomment-571173416 and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. It looks like this is a [Java TLS Bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/405), hoping java team will fix this in Java 11.0.8.

**Update**: The issue was fixed in latest Java 11 versions

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: It was bug in Java 11.0.7 version. Latest version of the Java fixed it. You can also use TLS 1.2 using the argument -Djdk.tls.client.protocols. Sample: `java -jar -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 app.jar  `